# Entity SQL: ORDER BY in a subquery not supported?

Tags: entity-framework

As an example, let's say I'm using Entity SQL (not LINQ or T-SQL) to query the Northwind database. I want to get the order date and company name for all the orders placed on the *most-recent 5 dates that exist in the database*. This is fairly simple in T-SQL, but I'm having a really hard time working out how to do it in Entity SQL, and I would appreciate any pointers.

Here's the query my code is generating:

```
SELECT [T_Orders].[OrderDate], [T_Orders].[ShippedDate], [T_Customers].[CompanyName]
FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [T_Orders]
INNER JOIN [NorthwindContext].[Customers] AS [T_Customers] ON [T_Customers].[CustomerID] = [T_Orders].[CustomerID]
WHERE [T_Orders].[OrderDate] IN 
    (SELECT VALUE DISTINCT [S_Orders].[OrderDate]
     FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [S_Orders] 
     ORDER BY [S_Orders].[OrderDate] DESC LIMIT(5))
ORDER BY [T_Orders].[OrderDate] ASC SKIP(@skip) LIMIT(@limit)
```

This gets me the following error:

> 'S_Orders.OrderDate' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near member access expression, line 5, column 143.

If I take out the ORDER BY/LIMIT clause in the subquery, I get no errors, and my query returns all the rows in the table. If add a TOP(5) to the SELECT in the subquery, then I get the oldest 5 dates, but not the most-recent 5 dates.

Can anyone tell me what I've gotten wrong in my Entity SQL syntax, or suggest another way of getting the results I want using Entity SQL?

**Update**

Thanks to Thit Lwin Oo's suggestions, I was able to work out the following query that did the trick for me.

```
SELECT [T_Orders].[OrderDate], [T_Orders].[ShippedDate], [T_Customers].[CompanyName]
FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [T_Orders]
INNER JOIN [NorthwindContext].[Customers] AS [T_Customers] ON [T_Customers].[CustomerID] = [T_Orders].[CustomerID]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [T_Orders].[OrderDate]
    FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [T_Orders]
    GROUP BY [T_Orders].[OrderDate]
    ORDER BY [T_Orders].[OrderDate] DESC LIMIT(5)
) AS REC ON ([T_Orders].[OrderDate] = REC.[OrderDate])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. How about this one.

```
SELECT [T_Orders].[OrderDate], [T_Orders].[ShippedDate], [T_Customers].[CompanyName]
FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [T_Orders]
INNER JOIN [NorthwindContext].[Customers] AS [T_Customers] ON [T_Customers].[CustomerID] = [T_Orders].[CustomerID]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP(5) MAX([T_Orders].[OrderDate]) AS [OrderDate]
    FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [T_Orders]
    GROUP BY [T_Orders].[CustomerID]
) AS REC ON ([T_Orders].[OrderDate] = REC.[OrderDate])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was even closer. I had to change a few things, but I got what I needed. I put the query I ended up with up in the question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT [T_Orders].[OrderDate], [T_Orders].[ShippedDate], [T_Customers].[CompanyName]
FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [T_Orders]
INNER JOIN [NorthwindContext].[Customers] AS [T_Customers] ON [T_Customers].[CustomerID] = [T_Orders].[CustomerID]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 5 [T_Orders].[CustomerID], MAX([T_Orders].[OrderDate]) [OrderDate]
    FROM [NorthwindContext].[Orders] AS [T_Orders]
    GROUP BY [T_Orders].[CustomerID]
) REC ON ([T_Customers].[CustomerID] = REC.[CustomerID] AND [T_Orders].[OrderDate] = REC.[OrderDate])
```

Comment: After fixing a couple minor syntax errors, that's close to what I'm looking for! However, it always returns exactly 5 rows, even if there are 20 orders that took place during the most-recent 5 dates in the Orders table. I need to return all 20 (or whatever).